# Node.js Mongodb geospatial query with find() issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geospatial

```
usercollection.find({
      "device_info.location" :
            $geoWithin : { $centerSphere :[[_latitude, _longitude]  , 100/3959]}}},
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) callback(err) else callback(null, result)
            });
```

As you can see it is a simple query for fetching documents that meet the location criteria, this works perfectly fine if I change this to findOne however in this case it just returns {}. The same query works perfectly fine when executed from the terminal. There are two records that are within this range and show up on the terminal as well.

Is there some specific reason why it behaves like this with find()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` provides its results to the callback as a [`Cursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html), not an array.  If you want an array you need to chain a call to [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray):

```
usercollection.find({ ...existing query... }).toArray(callback);
```

Comment: I did not realize it was a Cursor. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @insanoid My pleasure.  The docs are surprisingly vague on this rather important detail.